# A Good and SIMPLE Measure of regularity

Tags: mathematical-statistics, measurement, association-measure

I am dealing with grocery shoppers' transaction data and trying to measure how a customer regularly shops for a certain retailer. 
With the intershopping time (days), How can I measure each individual's shopping regularity? 
Can I use just standard deviation? or Can I use a measure of volatility?